# how to open reference in new or next split in vim

Tags: vim, c, split-window, ctags

When I move over a key word and then hit `^]`, it will jump to the definition in thecurrently active split. How can I keep the current split the same and instead open the definition in another split window (either vertical or horizontal)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`<C-]>` doesn't jump to the reference of the word under the cursor, it jumps to its *definition*.

Anyway, you can use `<C-w>]` to open the tag in a new window.

See `:help window-tag`.

Answer (score 1):

You can remap `^]` with the following commands:

`nnoremap <C-]> :only<bar>vsplit<CR>:execute "tag" . expand('<cword>')<CR>`

Put that in your `.vimrc` and restart vim.

Reference:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33603586/4752883